# Does the IEnumerator of .Net IList provide the order of the list?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, ienumerator

Can I assume that the `IEnumerator` I get from an `IList` (by calling the `GetEnumerator` method from the `IEnumerable` interface) will give me the items in the order of the list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, because IList is an interface, and an implementation can enumerate items in any order. For instance, I could implemenent WeirdList : IList, and have it enumerate items in any way, including non-deterministically. If you use a List(T) on the other hand, it guarantees to enumerate items in the order they are stored in the list.

**Edit**: That being said, as many others point out, most implementations will follow the semantics of List(T). Although that wasn't what you asked ;)

Comment: +1 Most implementations will be similar but it would be a huge mistake to write code based on that fact.

Comment: I'd caution against code that tries to validate the semantics of data structures that have pretty hard and fast semantics. This is ok for your Unit tests, to make sure MyListImpl matches what IList implies, but the actual production code shouldn't have those checks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will do exactly that, for any decent implementation of `IList` at least. A good `IList` should always enumerate its elements in the same order as in which the list is indexed.

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 };

IEnumerator<int> enumtor = list.GetEnumerator();
while (enumtor.MoveNext())
{
    Console.Write(enumtor.Current);
}
```

Prints `112358`.

Comment: There is now way to guarantee that the person who implemented the IList followed this principle, there are some examples where it would make sense to not return it in order.

Comment: There is no guarantee, but it's a generally valid assumption, and it's *supposed* to be a valid assumption.

Comment: I agree it should be a valid assumption, but experience tought me that programmers sometimes do crazy things in their code :)

Comment: True. From the little context of the question though, I think this is just someone new to .NET wondering what the usual behaviour is, and that's how I answered it.

Answer (score 0):

The enumerator should give you access to the objects inside the list relative to their position in memory which would be the same as using the indexer of the list going from 0 to Length < 1 in a for loop.

**Edit:** I answered specifically in regards to the .NET framework classes that implement IList,  should any other person implement these interfaces their actual implementation could be just about anything. So it depends on implementer.

Answer (score -1):

This will depend on the implementation of the IList